# Allow only specific IPs when accessing to a domain pattern in web.config

Tags: azure, iis, web-config

I need to restrict to specific IPs access to a pattern, domain in Azure WebApp (IIS) in my web. config file.
When an access, domain is sub.**admin.**.sub.domain.com (regexp) only specific IP range must be allowed.
I spent a lot of hours, but no success....

```
   <rule name="admin access" enabled="true">
      <match url="^(.+)" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" type="Pattern" pattern="^(.*?[.])?admin.(.*?[.])?sub.domain.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <security>
         <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
            <add ipAddress="111.111.111.111" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="true" />
         </ipSecurity>
      </security>
   </rule>
```

When I put this code into my web.config, I got "Internal server error".
Any ideas?

THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the ipSecurity config could be set in the url rewrite config setting and use the type in url conditions.

This is the reason why you get the 500 error.

If you want to check the IP in url rewrite rule, I suggest you could check REMOTE_ADDR in conditions.

Like below:

```
     <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="admin access" enabled="true">
      <match url="^(.+)" />
      <conditions   logicalGrouping="MatchAll" >
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"   pattern="^(.*?[.])?admin.(.*?[.])?sub.domain.com$" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="111.111.111.111"   />
      </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="the right url" />

    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```